# Putting UISearchBar in a custom UITableview causing weird animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uisearchcontroller

Basically, I am including two buttons located below the navigation bar. And below these two buttons, there is a UITableView, with the UISearchBar as its header view. However, when I click the search bar, the animation moves very strange.
[image: After adding animations to the tableview frame]

Then I try to use animation to move the UITableView together with the search bar to the top, 
[image: After adding animations to the tableview frame]

the animation goes like this [image: After adding animations to the tableview frame]

The code added to the table view is like this:

```
- (BOOL) searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.myTableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                     animations:^{
                         self.myTableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
                     }
                     completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

I am wondering how to move the UISearchBar to the top of the screen, together with the whole table view with smooth animations.

Comment: It would help if you included other screenshots. The question is not clear (at least to me).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL) searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                         animations:^{
                             [ searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x, 0, searchBar.frame.size.width, searchBar.frame.size.height)];
                             [self.myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(myTableView.frame.origin.x, searchBar.frame.size.height, self.myTableView.frame.size.width, myTableView.frame.size.height)];
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    return YES;
}
```

try this code